# Dynamically change angular 6 sidebar's width and mode

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing an app with Angular 6, where I want to have a responsive sidebar, and decided to use angular material's sidebar module. The problem is: I want for the sidebar to have a collapsed mode that is not entirely hidden, which isn't how angular sidebar's work, so I did something similar to [this](https://medium.com/@harkiratsingh.026/angular-6-mini-variant-drawer-d5326be55dd1) (Medium.com).

Now, the behaviour I want for my sidebar: I want it to be able to be collapsed or expanded while the resoltion of the screen is higher than 1366 of width, and have mode set to `'side'`, and when the resolution is smaller than that, I want it set to `'side'` if collapsed, or `'over'` if expanded.

How I did that:

```
<div id="complete-container">
  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav opened="True" [style.width]="isExpanded ? expandedWidth : collapsedWidth" [mode]="mode">
      <app-sidebar *ngIf="isExpanded" [version]="version" [isExpanded]="isExpanded" (isExpandedEvent)="collapse($event)"></app-sidebar>
      <app-collapsed-sidebar *ngIf="!isExpanded" [version]="version" [isExpanded]="isExpanded" (isExpandedEvent)="collapse($event)"></app-collapsed-sidebar>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content [style.margin-left]="isExpanded ? expandedWidth : collapsedWidth">
      <p>Main content</p>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

And, on my component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  isExpanded: boolean;

  expandedWidth = '220px';
  collapsedWidth = '80px';
  mode: string;

  constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 1366px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.mobileQuery.matches) {
      this.isExpanded = false;
    } else {
      this.isExpanded = true;
    }
    this.mode = 'side';
  }

  collapse(change: boolean) {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
    if (this.mobileQuery.matches && this.isExpanded) {
      this.mode = 'over';
    } else {
      this.mode = 'side';
    }
  }
}
```

`collapse()` is the method that gets called when you click the button to expand/collapse the sidebar.

Now, what is the problem with that? When my resolution width is smaller than 1366, and the sidebar goes from expanded to collapsed, the main content gets displaced, like if the sidebar was set to mode `'side'` (which is correct), but it's width was the one while it is expanded, and not collapsed.

Images of how it is behaving:

Fullscreen expanded (working ok)
[image: Fullscreen expanded (working ok)]

Fullscreen collapsed (working ok)
[image: Fullscreen collapsed]

Small screen expanded (working ok)
[image: Smallscreen expanded]

Small screen collapsed (weird space between sidebar and main content)
[image: Small screen collapsed]

Does anyone know why is it behaving like this? Or how should it be done to get the expected result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem, one fix could be enabling `[autosize]="true"` on `<mat-sidenav-container>`

You also can look at: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6743
It provides some other hacky workarounds.